# Is it better to interact with ABIs directly from the frontend or through an API?

Tags: solidity, web3js, evm, ethers.js

This is a question about good practices. I could use web3 or ethers to parse the ABI of my contracts and add Javascript functions to trigger those methods directly from the frontend, or I could move all interactions with the EVM to the backend and just have api calls in the frontend. Which is the best approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I could move all interactions with the EVM to the backend

Your backend cannot sign transactions on the behalf of the user, as if you could do this, you would be able to steal their money and this is the problem the blockchain was invented to solve in the first place. So what you are suggesting does not work for any generic website.

Comment: Ah, good point which I missed :)

Comment: @Mikko Ohtanaa if I trigger a method in the ABI wouldn't it open the user's wallet and allow him to sign even if called from the backend?

Comment: That is not how blockchains work.

Comment: As long as signing transactions is required, the interaction with the contract's ABI needs to take place in the frontend. This is the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

It of course depends on your needs.

Adding an extra layer (API calls) brings more complexity and makes the project harder to maintain. But it also allows you to for example log the requests in a database (easier to do in the backend) and to adjust the requests and/or results in some way, if needed.

In general, if you don't have a clear need to use a backend route, I would suggest call the contracts directly. Of course make sure the users never see your provider secrets, or stuff like that - this isn't a problem if you only utilize the users' own wallet connections.

Comment: thanks @Lauri Peltonen. That was very clear.